# Powershell get base64 public key of new self-signed certificate

Tags: powershell, certificate

I know how to create a new self-signed certificate in powershell, but I'd like to get a base64 public key of that newly-created certificate, e.g. for export to services that want base64-encoded DER.

For example:

```
$dateformatted = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$certname = "the-cert-name-$dateformatted"
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

How to get the public key of `$cert` in base64 format?

Answer (score 2):

The [`Export-Certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-certificate) powershell command gives you the binary version of the public key, and then you can use standard .Net classes to read those bytes and write them back out again as base64.

```
$dateformatted = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$certname = "the-cert-name-$dateformatted"
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
$binaryFile = New-TemporaryFile
$exported = Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $binaryFile
$binaryContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$binaryFile")
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binaryContent) | Out-File "$certname.cer"
Write-Output "Wrote $certname.cer"
remove-item $binaryFile
```